# Same jquery for many multiple image upload button on one page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I my using PHP form, in which i want to submit form with many multiple image upload button.
In my page many multiple upload  button are there .I want to use same jquery for all multiple image upload button with different name and id .

My code is :

```
  <input type="file" id="files" name="dog_img[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>

   <input type="file" id="files1" name="dog_img1[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>

   <input type="file" id="files2" name="dog_img2[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>

  <input type="file" id="files3" name="dog_img3[]" class="upload-img" onchange="readURL(this);" multiple>
```

Jquery code is:

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.upload-img').change(function () {
     var co =0;
     var len =5;

   for (var i=0; i < len; i++)
   {



   (function (j, self) 
    {

     var reader = new FileReader()
     reader.onload = function (e) {
     var image = new Image();
     image.src = e.target.result;
     image.onload = function () {
     var height = this.height;
     var width = this.width;
      if (height < 700 || width < 1000) {
       alert("Height and Width must not exceed 1024px.");
      return false;
   }
  };
   co++;
  $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="col-md-2" id="pip">
   <span id="'+[co]+'" data-id="'+[co]+'" class="click-form">
     <img class="imageThumb" src="' + e.target.result 
     + '"/>' + '</span><span data-id="'+[co]+'" class="remove">X
       </span></div>');

}

    reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
    })
    (i, this);
   }

   });
  });
```

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code you will get files length

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.upload-img').bind('change',function () {
     var co =0;
     var len =5;
         var num_of_images =  this.files.length;
        alert(num_of_images);
       for (var i=0; i < len; i++)
       {

       (function (j, self) 
        {

         var reader = new FileReader()
         reader.onload = function (e) {
             var image = new Image();
             image.src = e.target.result;
             image.onload = function () {
       console.log("image",image);
             var height = this.height;
             var width = this.width;
              if (height < 700 || width < 1000) {
               alert("Height and Width must not exceed 1024px.");
              return false;
           }
          };
           co++;
              $('.gallery-row').append('<div class="col-md-2" id="pip">            <span id="'+[co]+'" data-id="'+[co]+'" class="click-form">                <img class="imageThumb" src="' + e.target.result + '"/>' + '</span><span data-id="'+[co]+'" class="remove">X </span></div>');
            reader.readAsDataURL(self.files[j])
            }


        })
        (i, this);
       }

       });
  });
```

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/fg247L2x/1/)

I changed this `var num_of_images =  this.files.length;` instead of `var num_of_images =  $(".upload-img")[0].files.length;`

**Updated fiddle**

[updated fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/gnanavelr/fg247L2x/2/)

Comment: No, i want to show the preview of all uploaded image through same function

Comment: @varsha, Fiddle updated. check now

Comment: okay... what was wrong with my code?

Comment: I changed this `var num_of_images =  this.files.length;` instead of `var num_of_images =  $(".upload-img")[0].files.length;`

Comment: its working fine?

Comment: i cannot upload. its says please login first.

Comment: please refresh the page

Comment: seems you didnt use my code

Comment: Yes i make the changes..you said

Comment: div is wrong and you commented some lines of code.

Comment: and I remove `onchange="readURL(this);"` from html file upload.

Comment: Im getting this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/wKGmw.png

Comment: I need onchange="readURL(this);" function on input  type

Comment: you need to remove `onchange="readURL(this);"` from html.

Comment: hy i need some more help!

Comment: This solution working or not?

Comment: yeah i removed onclick function from button

Comment: hy i need some more help! ? what is the issue?